# bash - How to break a long string by word count into multiple string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to break a long string by the word count and then continue display and break once every certain number of words reached.

For example.

I have a string :

```
value="Aug 04 03:49:00.082205 ALERT IPX-NG dropped -- total: 4693845, count: 39254, rate: 1.88% ; OUTPUT QUEUE frampedd: active=1, delivered=73265000210 Aug 04 09:43:00.795817 ALERT IPX-NG dropped -- total: 4765909, count: 72064, rate: 1.91% ; OUTPUT QUEUE frampedd: active=0, delivered=74220627600"
```

my expected output is :

```
Aug 04 03:49:00.082205 ALERT IPX-NG dropped -- total: 4693845, count: 39254, rate: 1.88% ; OUTPUT QUEUE frampedd: active=1, delivered=73265000210
Aug 04 09:43:00.795817 ALERT IPX-NG dropped -- total: 4765909, count: 72064, rate: 1.91% ; OUTPUT QUEUE frampedd: active=0, delivered=74220627600"
```

I couldn't use by character count as the number will be vary. So the best choice is to use word count.

EDIT:

Hi Guys,..i tried using the sed command and it seems to work!

sed 's/([^[:space:]]{1,}[[:space:]]{1,}){19}/&\n/'

thanks those who helps..you can give me better suggestions if there is :D.. would hope for pure bash command as i'm unable to install any other extension on the server.

Comment: for every 18 words, the string will break and become substring..then continue...

for example :
"Aug 04 03:49:00.082205 ALERT IPX-NG dropped -- total: 4693845, count: 39254, rate: 1.88% ; OUTPUT QUEUE frampedd: active=1, delivered=73265000210"
   
has 18 words..so after this 18 words, i want to break the string into another sentence and cont go on

Answer (score 2):

If all the string count doesn't change, you can use `xargs`

```
$ value="Aug 04 03:49:00.082205 ALERT IPX-NG dropped -- total: 4693845, count: 39254, rate: 1.88% ; OUTPUT QUEUE frampedd: active=1, delivered=73265000210 Aug 04 09:43:00.795817 ALERT IPX-NG dropped -- total: 4765909, count: 72064, rate: 1.91% ; OUTPUT QUEUE frampedd: active=0, delivered=74220627600"

$ xargs -n 19 <<< "$value"
Aug 04 03:49:00.082205 ALERT IPX-NG dropped -- total: 4693845, count: 39254, rate: 1.88% ; OUTPUT QUEUE frampedd: active=1, delivered=73265000210
Aug 04 09:43:00.795817 ALERT IPX-NG dropped -- total: 4765909, count: 72064, rate: 1.91% ; OUTPUT QUEUE frampedd: active=0, delivered=74220627600
```

The [`xargs man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) page says this about the flag `-n`

```
-n max-args, --max-args=max-args
        Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than
        max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s
        option) is exceeded, unless the -x option is given, in which
        case xargs will exit.
```

Comment: This is a nice approach. In fact, you can calculate the number by doing `res="${value//[^ ]}"` and then `${#res}` will contain 37. This removes everything but spaces in the string, so to get the number of words you just need to count the characters in the result.

Comment: Note, this command will not work as expected if string contains arguments to echo for example if the string contains `-n` as a word it will not be printed.

Comment: Is xargs usable for all Linux system? Or is there way using sed?

Comment: It comes as part of `GNU findutils`, it you have it installed, `xargs` will be present and yes it is usable!

Comment: @guohaolee `sed 's/\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\{19\}/&\n/'` should work on all seds.

Comment: @inian. .thanks! Will check on it later if it's supported

Comment: @guohaolee: don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

In AWK:

```
awk '{{gsub(/^value="|"$/,""); for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i%19?" ":"\n")}' file
```

or if your string does not in fact start with `value="`, you can loose the `gsub`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i%19?" ":"\n")}' file
```

Comment: instead of hard-coding 19, you can say NF/2 + 1. Also, I think it is not the string staring with `value="`, but a variable declaration.

Comment: You are right but I kind of expected there to more that two sets of data to process.

Comment: Hi , i am actually assigning the string to a variable name "value"..so when i call out..i'll just  "echo $value"

Comment: OK, then you: `echo $value|awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i%19?" ":"\n")}`.